# XElement add prefix only

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file like:

```
<myPrefix:Catalog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
 xmlns:myPrefix="clr-namespace:........">

  <myPrefix:Item Name="Item1" Mode="All" />
  <myPrefix:Item Name="Item2" Mode="Single" />

</myPrefix:Catalog>
```

With C# I create a new Item like:

```
XContainer container = XElement.Parse(xml);
XElement xmlTree = 
   new XElement("Item",
      new XAttribute("Name", item.Name),
      new XAttribute("Mode", item.Mode));
```

As you can see I don't add the "myPrefix" prefix. Can anyone tell me how i can do that? I don't want to declarde the xmlns again. Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 1:**
If you add the namespace attribute aswell to the element this will force it to add the prefix. But you still end up with the xmlns attribute in the node. <strike>To remove it you'll probably, as Jeff says, need to utilize XmlWriter.</strike>

**Edit 2:**
<strike>To get the EXACT XML you want you need to create the root element aswell:</strike>

**Edit 3:**
OK. I found a way to get what you want without XmlWriter:

```
var xml = "<myPrefix:Catalog xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:sys=\"clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib\" xmlns:myPrefix=\"clr-namespace:........\"><myPrefix:Item Name=\"Item1\" Mode=\"All\" /></myPrefix:Catalog>";

XNamespace presentation = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
XNamespace xaml = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
XNamespace mscorlib = "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib";
XNamespace myPrefix = "clr-namespace:.......";

XElement container = XElement.Parse(xml);

var xmlTree = new XElement("Item",
               new XAttribute("Name", "Item2"),
               new XAttribute("Mode", "Single"));

container.Add(xmlTree);

foreach (var el in container.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
  el.Name = myPrefix.GetName(el.Name.LocalName);
  var atList = el.Attributes().ToList();
  el.Attributes().Remove();
  foreach (var at in atList)
  {
    if (el.Name.LocalName == "Catalog" && at.Name.LocalName != "xmlns")
      continue;
    el.Add(new XAttribute(at.Name.LocalName, at.Value));
  }
}

container.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", xaml));
container.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "sys", mscorlib));
container.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "myPrefix", myPrefix));
```

**Edit 4:**
Apparently there was an easier way... a LOT easier... see the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it won't work. The result is like:

<Item Name="Item3" Mode="Single" xmlns="clr-namespace:......." />

Comment: @Peter: It will appear that way if the element is the root.  It it is not the root, then it will be prefixed if the namespace is declared in an ancestor.

Comment: @Peter: This is just how the LINQ to XML serializer works.  I don't know if it is even possible without going back and using an `XmlWriter`.

Comment: @Jeff, hm ok thanks. Maybe anyone knows a way and else I will try XmlWriter.

Comment: @Sani Thanks a lot! It works for me :) Now i only have to remove the xmlns.

Comment: @Peter: Made a workaround for you that should work IF the existing XML is what is presented above. Otherwise you can tweak the code to your liking.

Comment: @Sani: Thanks for your example! I add xmlTree to the root container, so I don't have to create the root. I only need something to delete the xmlns.

Comment: Anyone a suggestion how i can remove only the second xmlns:myPrefix=".." ?

Comment: @Peter: Only way to do that, that I've found without resorting to XmlWriter, is to create the root element aswell as in the above example.

Comment: @Sani: Hm and how can I do it with XmlWriter? Create a root is not an option, because the xmlTree will be added to a XContainer (with already a root).

Comment: @Peter: I've got a working example for you now... Without XmlWriter... :)

Comment: @Peter: While my version works for your example you should really look at the other examples which are more correct.

Answer (score 10):

```
    XElement container = XElement.Parse(xml);
    XNamespace myPrefix = container.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("myPrefix");

    XElement xmlTree = new XElement(myPrefix + "Item",     
                            new XAttribute("Name", item.Name), 
                            new XAttribute("Mode", item.Mode));

    container.Add(xmlTree);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to construct any new elements in the namespace. Assuming you know the prefix of the namespace you want in the XML sample then do it as follows:

```
    var xml = "<myPrefix:Catalog xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:sys=\"clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib\" xmlns:myPrefix=\"clr-namespace:........\"><myPrefix:Item Name=\"Item1\" Mode=\"All\" /></myPrefix:Catalog>";

    XElement catalog = XElement.Parse(xml);

    XNamespace myP = catalog.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("myPrefix");

    catalog.Add(new XElement(myP + "Item", new XAttribute("Name", "foo"), new XAttribute("Mode", "bar")));
```